# Scrollview in Grid View Pager not working on Android Wear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, wear-os

I'm developing an app for smartwatches and I have a ScrollView (vertical) contains in GridViewPager which is itself contains in a FrameLayout.

The vertical scroll is working on a Sony SmartWatch 3 but not working on a Moto 360 (1st gen).

Here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" />

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</FrameLayout>
```

And inside the GridViewPager :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/wl_blue">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/very_long_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/wl_blue"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working on the Moto 360 ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it because of the round screen ?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue as yourself. Seems that the GridViewPager on the Moto 360 handles touches differently than other devices. Other devices I've tested on (including other round watches) the touch is passed from the GridViewPager to the scrollview but with the Moto 360 the GridViewPager consumes the touch itself.